# How to get the calling number from SIM900A?

Tags: arduino, sim900

I want to get the calling number in SIM900A when it connect with Arduino and receiving call. This is my code

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(7, 8); 

void setup()
{   
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Initializing..."); 
}

void loop()
{
 //dosomething();
}
```

and i got this in Serial Mornitor (when it got Receiving Call) :

```
RING

+CLIP: "0945000000",161,"",,"Ky",0

RING

+CLIP: "0945000000",161,"",,"Ky",0
```

0945000000 : this is the number i want to get to compare with the other, Although tried many ways, but it not work. Thanks for help.

Comment: Basically you need to read the serial in the loop and parse the message that you read. What did you try?

Comment: Can you post your code of what you tried?